# Filling a n x 3 range with formulas that contain iteratable reference to a list in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill a range of n rows and 3 columns with 3 formulas, one in each column.

The first column should contain a date range.

I fill it this way:

```vb
Sub FillDate()

    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim row As Long

    startDate = "01.08.2019"
    endDate = "07.08.2019"
    row = 2
    Do Until startDate = endDate + 1
        Range("A" & row).Value = startDate
        startDate = startDate + 1
        row = row + 1
    Loop  
End Sub
```

This gives me the A column with dates from 01.08.2019 to 07.08.2019 starting from the second row.

In columns B and C I'd like to specify tow formulas.

Formula for column B should look as follows:

```vb
=COUNTIF('Sheet (i)'!G$2:G$5000, $A2)
```

where `i` is an iterator so that formula in B2 should look as

```vb
=COUNTIF('Sheet (1)'!G$2:G$5000, $A2)
```

and formula in B3 should look as

```vb
=COUNTIF('Sheet (2)'!G$2:G$5000, $A3)
```

and so forth.

This formula looks up for the value in cell A2 and calculates how many times this value is found in the range G$2:G$5000 on the sheet named Sheet (1).

Formula for column C should look as follows:

```vb
=ROUND(MEDIAN($B$2:$B$n), 0)
```

where n is the number of rows in column A on the current sheet.

Like

```vb
=ROUND(MEDIAN($B$2:$B$8), 0)
```

I've come with the following, ehm, solution:

```vb
Sub Fill()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim i As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

     strFormulas(1) = "=COUNTIF('Sheet (1)'!G$2:G$5000, $A2)"
     strFormulas(2) = "=ROUND(MEDIAN($B$2:$B$8), 0)"

     .Range("C2:D2").Formula = strFormulas
     .Range("C2:D8").FillDown
End With
End Sub
```

However, this only fills the column C with proper formula.

**Question: how do I fill the column B so that B2 cell contains `=COUNTIF('Sheet (1)'!G$2:G$5000, $A2)`, B3 cell contains `=COUNTIF('Sheet (2)'!G$2:G$5000, $A2)` and so on up to `=COUNTIF('Sheet (8)'!G$2:G$5000, $A2)`**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Btw you're off a column `.Range("C2:D2")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Fill()

Dim strFormula_template As String
Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim iCt As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

    strFormula_template = "=COUNTIF('Sheet (count)'!G$2:G$5000, $Axx)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=ROUND(MEDIAN($C$2:$C$8), 0)"

    For iCt = 1 To 7
        strFormulas(1) = Replace(strFormula_template, "count", iCt)
        strFormulas(1) = Replace(strFormulas(1), "xx", iCt + 1)
        .Range("C1:D1").Offset(iCt, 0).Formula = strFormulas
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Is it possible to ask the user to provide the sheet name without having to specify the name as a string in the argument of COUNTIF?  If I initialize strFormula_template = "=COUNTIF('Somename (count)'!G$2:G$5000, $Axx)" and Somename does not exist, Excel shows File open dialog. So the sheet name should always exist before this function runs. Is there any way I could specify a custom name variable by asking for the sheet name with InputBox()?

Comment: You may ask for a string (with InputBox) and check if this sheet name exists!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478282/vba-check-if-sheet-exists-object-required-error

Comment: Thank you. So the way to use a dynamic sheet name in the formula without having to strictly specify the sheet name in the code (like in the above example) would be to 1) create a temporary sheet with the name specified in =COUNTIF('Sheet (count)'!G$2:G$5000, $Axx), 2) Ask the user for the sheet name 3) Rename the name in the formula based on the input 4) Delete this temporary sheet. Correct? In the example above one has to always edit formula in the code before running macro in order to specify the proper sheet name. Leaving non-existing sheet forces XL to ask for the file.

Comment: How do you start the vba macro? Why don't you know the sheet name? Is it possible to use "ActiveSheet"? Is there a possibility to identify the sheet where you want to run this macro? (e.g. Range("A1").value = "Header of important sheet" ;-))


Is the

Comment: Does the number of sheets vary? Is it always the first sheet where you want these formulas?