# How do I fill a 5 x 2 range with 5 literals in one column and 5 formulas in another in a single run with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to automatically fill a `5 x 2` range with text and corresponding formulas. Consider we take columns `D` and `E`. The resulting range of cells should look as follows:

```
| D       | E                             |
|---------|-------------------------------|
| Average | =ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$Bxx),0) |
| Maximum | =MAX($B2:$B41)                |
| Median  | =ROUND(MEDIAN($B2:$B41); 0)   |
| Total   | =COUNTA(Sheet!A$2:A$90000)    |
| Total2  | =COUNTA('Sheet {2}'!A2:A8000) |
```

I thought that I could fill the whole range with pairs text, formula. I've created the following code:

```vb
Sub FillSummary()
Dim strFormulas(1 To 10) As Variant
Dim wsa As Worksheet: Set wsa = ActiveSheet

With wsa
    strFormulas(1) = "Average"
    strFormulas(2) = "=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$Bxx),0)"
    strFormulas(3) = "Maximum"
    strFormulas(4) = "=MAX($B2:$Bxx)"
    strFormulas(5) = "Median"
    strFormulas(6) = "=ROUND(MEDIAN($B2:$Bxx); 0)"
    strFormulas(7) = "Total"
    strFormulas(6) = "=COUNTA(Sheet!A$2:A$90000)"
    strFormulas(9) = "Total2"
    strFormulas(10) = "=COUNTA('Sheet {2}'!A2:A8000)"
    .Range("D2:E2").Formula = strFormulas
    .Range("D2:E6").FillDown

End With
End Sub
```

**Important moment here: I need to set different cell addresses every time the code runs. That is why I have specified Bxx instead of specific addresses.**

I planned to use Replace() after the formulas are added like:

`strFormulas(1) = Replace(xx, "41", sheetName)`

However, the code fails when executing line `.Range("D2:E2").Formula = strFormulas`. What am I doing wrong?

This code runs OK:

```vb
Sub FillDAUSummary()
Dim strFormulas(1 To 10) As Variant
Dim wsa As Worksheet: Set wsa = ActiveSheet


With wsa
    .Range("D2").Formula = "Average"
    .Range("E2").Formula = "=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$B41),0)"
    .Range("D3").Formula = "Maximum"
    .Range("E3").Formula = "=MAX($B2:$B41)"
    .Range("D4").Formula = "Median"
    .Range("E4").Formula = "=ROUND(MEDIAN($B2:$B41), 0)"
    .Range("D5").Formula = "Total"
    .Range("E5").Formula = "=COUNTA(Sheet!A$2:A$90000)"
    .Range("D6").Formula = "Total2"
    .Range("E6").Formula = "=COUNTA('Sheet {2}'!A2:A8000)"
End With
End Sub
```

**However, it has a shortcoming. I had to specify string range: `B$2:$B41`. In fact, I would like to specify the end of the range on every run.**
Thank you.

Comment: You need a 2D array.

Comment: @BigBen Nailed it. `Dim strFormulas(1 to 5, 1 to 2) ...`

Comment: Also the formulas must be viable formula: `"=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$Bxx),0)"` will error since `xx` is not a valid row number.

Comment: Once you have the 2D array use `.Range("D2:E6").Formula = strFormulas` to place the whole array in the cells.

Comment: @Scott Craner, I need somehow a universal approach because the end cell of the range may vary. I planned using Replace() like it's said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138084/filling-a-n-x-3-range-with-formulas-that-contain-iteratable-reference-to-a-list/58138611

Comment: @StacyRyutt the formula must work at each level of the replace.  You can not insert a garbage formula then replace to make work.  You need to have a functional formula then replace parts.  for ex: `"=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$B1040000),0)"` then replace the `1040000` with the correct row number.

Comment: But you can also use a variable in the formula by setting the variable to the row desired then use: `"=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$B" & rw & "),0)"`

Comment: @BigBen I get `Wrong number of dimensions` when initializing the array as `Dim strFormulas(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant`. Any clues?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. In fact, I have used a 'fake' formula once, like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138084/filling-a-n-x-3-range-with-formulas-that-contain-iteratable-reference-to-a-list/58138611

Comment: If you look though it does the replace before putting the formula in the cell, so the formula is a viable formula.  You are trying to place the formula in the cell prior to replace hence the error.

Comment: @ScottCraner Any clues why `Dim strFormulas(1 to 5, 1 to 2)` raises the `Wrong dimensions error`?

Comment: @ScottCraner, thanks for `"=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$B" & rw & "),0)"`. Didn't know you could do that. Fantastic!

Comment: @ScottCraner, is it possible to replace sheet name in here `"=COUNTA(Sheet!A$2:A$90000)"`? "=COUNTA(rw & "!A$2:A$90000)" doesn't seem to work. Where am I failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub FillSummary()
    Dim strFormulas(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim wsa As Worksheet: Set wsa = ActiveSheet

    Dim rw As Long
    rw = 41

    With wsa
        strFormulas(1, 1) = "Average"
        strFormulas(1, 2) = "=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$B" & rw & "),0)"
        strFormulas(2, 1) = "Maximum"
        strFormulas(2, 2) = "=MAX($B2:$B41)"
        strFormulas(3, 1) = "Median"
        strFormulas(3, 2) = "=ROUND(MEDIAN($B2:$B41), 0)"
        strFormulas(4, 1) = "Total"
        strFormulas(4, 2) = "=COUNTA(Sheet!A$2:A$90000)"
        strFormulas(5, 1) = "Total2"
        strFormulas(5, 2) = "=COUNTA('Sheet {2}'!A2:A8000)"
        .Range("D2:E6").Formula = strFormulas


    End With
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub FillSummary()
    Dim strFormulas(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim wsa As Worksheet: Set wsa = ActiveSheet

    Dim rw As Long
    rw = 41

    With wsa
        strFormulas(1, 1) = "Average"
        strFormulas(1, 2) = "=ROUNDUP(AVERAGE($B2:$Bxx),0)"
        strFormulas(2, 1) = "Maximum"
        strFormulas(2, 2) = "=MAX($B2:$B41)"
        strFormulas(3, 1) = "Median"
        strFormulas(3, 2) = "=ROUND(MEDIAN($B2:$B41), 0)"
        strFormulas(4, 1) = "Total"
        strFormulas(4, 2) = "=COUNTA(Sheet!A$2:A$90000)"
        strFormulas(5, 1) = "Total2"
        strFormulas(5, 2) = "=COUNTA('Sheet {2}'!A2:A8000)"

        strFormulas(1, 2) = Replace(strFormulas(1, 2), "xx", rw)

        .Range("D2:E6").Formula = strFormulas


    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you!  Any way to also replace name of the worksheet? `"=COUNTA(rw & "'Sheet {2}'!A2:A8000)"` didn't work.

Comment: `"=COUNTA('" & rw & "'!A2:A8000)"`

Comment: I am speechless! So simple! Thank you for your help and yet more for being so descriptive and specific. Your code and comments helped a lot!